# Function.toString() not respecting closure scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var foo = (function(){
  var x = "bar";
  return function(){
    console.log(x);
  };
})();

console.log(foo.toString()); // function() {console.log(x);}

(foo)(); // 'bar'
eval('(' + foo.toString()+')()')); // error: x is undefined
```

**Why isn't the var `x` recorded as `"bar"` in `foo.toString()`?**

`foo` has a behavior that does not match its toString() value. `foo` always prints "bar", but looking at `foo.toString()` would not tell you this.

Is it related to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString#See_also)? If a decision was made not to decompile a function to get its toString() value, why not include the resolution of objects which rely on an external function's scope?

Is there a way to use the old method of decompilation to get the actual code behind a given function?

Comment: _"Function.toString() not respecting closure scope"_ - It's returning the string representation of the function code source, as you've seen. How could `toString()` do otherwise? Shown as a string, where would `x` actually go in the string?

Comment: After declaration, `foo` is a function which always prints "bar" in the console. I would expect its toString() value to be `console.log('bar')` instead of `console.log(x)` where `x` is undefined

Comment: If you want x to be a constant them just use a string literal directly in the inner function. x is always 'bar' in this simple example, but it is still a _variable_ - it is easy to create a similar example where the value of x can change each time the inner function is called. I don't think it is reasonable to expect toString() to figure out when a variable is or isn't really a pseudo-constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since javascript is function-scoped, it loses its scope information when it gets converted to string. So a newly created function from this string is not related to the original function.

There's two workarounds of mine:

first, instead making foo an IIFE, you can have it like :

```js
var foo = function(){
  var x = "bar";
  return function(){
    console.log(x);
  };
};
```

then calling eval('(' + foo.toString() + ')()()'), the scope gets created when you execute the function and passed down.

Or you can keep IIFE and when you invoke the eval('(' + foo.toString() + ')'), call it using apply or call methods and put x in the context object or pass in as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You are executing the anonymous function, so the return value is assigned to `foo`. If you use

```
var foo = function(){
  var x = "bar";
  return function(){
    console.log(x);
  };
};
```

`foo.toString()` shows the anonymous function and
`foo().toString()` the *returned* function

Your `eval` creates a new function from `foo.toString()`<sup>**1**</sup>, *not in any way related to the scope of the initial scope* [of the anonymous function that created `foo`], and executes that, so it results in a `ReferenceError` concerning `x`. There's nothing strange about that.

<sup>**1**</sup> `eval("function (){console.log(x);})()")`

Comment: The same problem exists in your example: `foo().toString()` results in `console.log(x)` even though its actual definition is closer to `console.log('bar')`. The toString() value doesn't reflect the fact that `x` was in the parent functions scope.

Comment: Yes there is nothing strange about the `eval()` statement. I would certainly expect it to create a new function with no reference to `x`. the thing that bothers me here is that the output from `foo.toString()` contains "x" instead of "bar". When `foo` is created, the value of `x` is "bar". Why doesn't the resulting `toString()` output `console.log("bar")`?

Comment: `foo.toString()` does nothing more than return a string representation of  `foo`. It can't evaluate/determine/guess the nature of `x`.